# proving $f: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C}): g \to I_n$ if G has odd order

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am having some trouble with proving that for a groupmorphism $f: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $G$ a group with odd order and for all $g \in G$ holds that the eigenvalues of $f(g)$ are real. Then I need to prove that $f(g)= I_n.$
I know that $f(g)$ is diagonizable for all $g \in G,$ but that's where it stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

If $a$ is a real diagonal matrix with the property $a^n=I$ for odd $n$, then $a=I$. Recall what the roots of degree $n$ of $1$ look like.

Comment: okay, so we have $f(g)=P^{-1}DP$ and $f(g)^n=I$. Then $I=P^{-1}D^nP$ which for odd $n$ means that $D=I$ so $f(g)=I$.